# Iterate through an image to replace all colors except one with black in php

Tags: php, image, iteration, gd

I need to iterate through all pixels in an image to replace all but one color with black so that I can define all regions of a particular color. The code below is not working, the image remains unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// open an image
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('sunset.jpg');
$x_val = imagesx($im);
$y_val = imagesy($im);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < $x_val; $i++) {
    $color_index = imagecolorat($im, $i, $i);
    $colourarray = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color_index);
    if ($colourarray[0] != 170 && $colourarray[1] != 0 && $colourarray[2] != 0) {

        $color_index = imagecolorat($im, $i, $i);

        imagecolorset($im, $color_index, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        $color_index = imagecolorat($im, $i, $i);
        imagecolorset($im, $color_index, 170, 0, 0);
    }
}


imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: You aren't saving it `imagejpeg($im, 'saved.jpg')`

Comment: Thanks. I see that this code is missing a loop though. One needs to loop through height and width. I'll post the code if I get it working.

Comment: If you were able to post a starting image and another one showing how it should look afterwards...